# Не работает last-child для изборажения в блоке, Почему?

Tags: css

Не работает nth-child(2) или last-child для изображения если между ними есть тег

```
<div class="post">
    <img data-src="@img/blog-1.jpg" alt="" />
    <p>13</p>
    <img data-src="@img/info/info-3.jpg" alt=""/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.post{

 img{

  &:first-child{
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }

  &:nth-child(2){
    float: right;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
  }
}
```

}

Comment: а почему вы одни свойства вкладываете в другие, я не прям гуру верстки но мне кажется так делать нельзя. скиньте ссылку на материал где вы это позаимствовали

Comment: last-child работает, nth-child(2) не работает, потому что там не img

Comment: Измените `&:nth-child(2)` на `&:nth-of-type(2)`

Comment: @ReijiAkkerman это называется CSS препроцессор. Поищите, ознакомьтесь, очень удобная вещь.

Comment: `last-child` продолжил бы работать, но в твоем коде его нет

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо пользователю [@UModeL](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/265406/umodel)
В моей ситуации сработало

```
Измените &:nth-child(2) на &:nth-of-type(2)
```